# Hasse diagram: Reverse divisibility.

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

Consider the set $X=\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ endowed with the order $$x\leq y\Leftrightarrow y|x,$$
that is, $x$ precedes $y$ if and only if $y$ is a divisor of $x$. Can anyone check whether my Hasse diagram below is correct? And what are the minimal and maximal elements?

[image]

I guess the minimal elements are $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$ and $10$ whereas the maximal elements are $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$. Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: And what’s the proof that those elements are the minimal/maximal elements?

Comment: In that exercise I was only supposed to find the minimal/maximal elements so I didn't bother writing a proof.

Comment: But for instance: $6$ is minimal element because if $x\leq 6\Rightarrow 6|x\Rightarrow x=6$ for $6$ is the only element of $X$ divisible by $6$.

Comment: Another example: $3$ is maximal element because if $3\leq x\Rightarrow x|3\Rightarrow x=3$ because $x=3$ is the only element of $X$ which divides $3$.

Comment: If you know about ideals then we have $\, y\ge x \iff y\mid x\iff (y)\supseteq (x),\,$ i.e. divides = contains for principal ideals. So the order is simply ideal containment.

Comment: Nice, I was just wondering the reason to consider that order, I guess you just provided it.